# How to use backslash(\) in access_id in application.properties in java springboot as backslash is considered as special character it seems

Tags: java, spring-boot, secret-key, application.properties, access-keys

I am providing access_id,secret_key and host in application.properties in java springboot.
But access_id provided by my team is containing backslash in it. eg:- "1_IN\abcde"
And access id will not be changed now.

My question is "How to use backslash() in access_id in application.properties in java springboot as backslash is considered as special character"?

I tried to replace with double slash i.e 1_IN\\abcde but still the error says :- "The access key ID you provided does not exist."

(Note :- "1_IN\abcde" works fine with python and node js as backend but issue with java)

Anyone could please help?

I have checked with my concern team and they confirmed access id is correct, you have to figure it out how to use in java.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "\\" instead of "\".

Comment: Tried this and got this error:-"aws-chunked content encoding is not supported."

Comment: @madhurikatiwari In your question you stated it caused `The access key ID you provided does not exist.`. Make up your mind.